# If X is NP-complete and Y is in NP, why Y must also be NP-complete

Tags: np

Suppose X and Y are decision problems for which X≤ P ​ Y, i.e., X is polynomial-time reducible to Y . If X is NP-complete and Y is in NP, why Y must also be NP-complete.

Comment: NP-complete is a subset of NP not the other way around.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: @Progman even though the question is not very well asked, I don't think it should be moved to the CS forum, because this question is about very basic notions of CS, which are also discussed in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If X is NP complete, in particular it is NP hard, that is, every NP problem Z is polynomial-time reducible to X, which in turn is polynomial-time reducible to Y, thus Y is also NP hard. Being both NP and NP hard means you're NP complete, therefore Y is NP complete.